# Linear map problem

Tags: linear-algebra

> Given that $T$ is a linear map $T:\Bbb R^3 \to \Bbb R^2$ and that
>   $$
> T\left(\matrix{1\\0\\0}\right) = \left(\matrix{1\\0}\right)\qquad T\left(\matrix{1\\1\\0}\right) = \left(\matrix{0\\-3}\right) \qquad T\left(\matrix{0\\-1\\1}\right) = \left(\matrix{3\\-3}\right)
> $$
>   find the value of
>   $$
> T\left(\matrix{3\\-1\\1}\right)
> $$

Trying to solve the above, so far had only dealt with questions with identity matrices like 
$$
T\left(\matrix{1\\0\\0}\right) \qquad T\left(\matrix{0\\1\\0}\right) \qquad T\left(\matrix{0\\0\\1}\right)
$$

Here are a couple of things i have tried answer should be $\left(\matrix{6\\-3}\right)$:
$$
3\left(\matrix{1\\0}\right) - 1\left(\matrix{0\\3}\right) + 1\left(\matrix{3\\3}\right) = \left(\matrix{6\\0}\right) \tag{$\times$}
$$
$$
{}
$$
$$
n_1\left(\matrix{1\\0}\right) + n_2\left(\matrix{0\\1}\right) + n_3\left(\matrix{3\\3}\right)\\
\implies\left(\matrix{n_1 + 3n_3\\n_2 + 3n_3}\right) = \left(\matrix{6\\2}\right)\tag{$\times$}
$$

Comment: You need to write $(3,-1,1)$ as a combination of the vectors $(1,0,0)$, $(1,1,0)$ and $(0,-1,1)$, i.e. you need $\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\lambda_3$ such that $(3,-1,1)=\lambda_1(1,0,0)+\lambda_2(1,1,0)+\lambda_3(0,-1,1)$, and then you know how to apply $T$ to this combination. You tried to use $3,-1,1$, but $3(1,0,0)-1(1,1,0)+(0,-1,1)=(2,0,1)\ne(3,-1,1)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're starting in the wrong end. We know that $T$ is linear, which means that $T(u + v) = T(u) + T(v)$. So we need to construct $\left(\matrix{3\\-1\\1}\right)$ out of the three given basis vectors in $\Bbb R^3$.

In this case, we have
$$
\left(\matrix{3\\-1\\1}\right) = 3\left(\matrix{1\\0\\0}\right) + \left(\matrix{0\\-1\\1}\right)
$$
so
$$
T\left(\matrix{3\\-1\\1}\right) = 3T\left(\matrix{1\\0\\0}\right) + T\left(\matrix{0\\-1\\1}\right)\\
 = 3\left(\matrix{1\\0}\right) + \left(\matrix{3\\-3}\right) = \left(\matrix{6\\-3}\right)
$$